# Concurrent activities

Tags: sentence-construction

Which of the following are used to say about concurrent activities? What are other ways.

> As he was sitting, Liza with surprise said what is that scar on your face.
>
> He was sitting that Liza with surprise said what is that scar on your face
>
> He was sitting when  Liza with surprise said what is that scar on your face.

Comment: It is conventional practice to surround direct speech with quotation marks....`"What is that scar on your face?"`  and **said** would become **asked**.

Answer (score 2):

Your first and last sentences could be used, with slight modifications to make them flow better:

> As he was sitting, Liza with surprise said, "What is that scar on your face?"

and

> He was sitting when Liza with surprise said, "What is that scar on your face?"

Note that "with surprise said" sounds quite literary, and in normal speech you'd probably hear "said with surprise."

As for other ways, you could use "while"/"whilst":

> While/whilst he was sitting, Liza with surprise said, "What is that scar on your face?"